# Error establishing a database connection only on some pages

Tags: errors

I have a Wordpress site which runs smoothly most of the time. However, from time to time, certain pages simply stops working and gives the good old "Error establishing a database connection", while the rest of the site continues to run without any issues whatsoever.

This problem goes away as soon as I restart the server, but usually comes back within a few days, sometimes within a day.

I can't find anything in the error logs (also, mysql.log is empty), so I'm not sure exactly what to do here, or even how to locate the root of the problem. The site goes into this "state" at seemingly random times, and I'm making no changes to it whatsoever.

I have of course googled around but none of the answers that I've found solves mmy particular problem.

Does anyone have a clue about what can be causing this? I'm using Ubuntu.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. Are you sure there is not a problem with your cache? Either browser cache or some cache plugins for WordPress?

Comment: Hmm, I never thought of that. But now when you mention it, I do have one or two cache plugins I think so that could be the problem. I'll look into it, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Sometimes the mysql server might not be accessible (especially on cheap hosting) and if a cache plugin tries to cache a page and gets a database error, it will save the error page as a page that will be served to visitor later, which ultimately result in you thinking there is something wrong with the database **at the moment**.

Comment: That could possibly explain it. I'll try disabling the caching and see what happens. I'll know if it worked within 2 weeks or so (to be safe).

Comment: Update: I disabled one of the cache plugins and the same thing happened again. However, this time, the entire site went down (so maybe the caching mitigated the problem?). I think I managed to track down the error in the logs to this line: "InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool", and luckily, google returned a decent amount of solutions to that problem so hopefully I should be able to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like there's an issue with your server setup and not with the website...